# How can I create a new node.js file?

Tags: node.js, file, save

I have search online how to create a new node.js file and I did it but could never find the file when I needed it after, it would say  1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnx8n.png , I would search for the new file that was created, but would never find it. I hope someone can answer this for me, I would appreciate your help so much. Thank you!

Comment: Please add in how you entered the node.js scripting environment.  Also recommend inserting the picture instead of linking it when you post a question.

Answer (score 0):

Your script likely does not have permissions to write to the `"C:\Program Files\*"` directory.  This directory is protected in the Windows OS and Administrator permissions is required.  Therefore, the file was never created.  When using the node installer, the nodejs icon from the start menu loads into the screen you have.  Use process.cwd() to see what your current directory is.  I do not know why `C:\Program Files\nodejs\` would be the default for node.js; it seems improper.

To fix (alternatives):

1. From nodejs shortcut which opens a Node.js window.  Use:

   ```
   // on Windows only
   > process.chdir(process.env['USERPROFILE'])
   > process.cwd()
   // 'C:\\Users\\me'
   // -- now work with the 'fs' module
   ```

   or
2. Open PowerShell.exe or cmd.exe.  Both will automatically open in your users directory `C:\Users\me` unless your $profile is configured differently from default.  If you had nodejs configure your PATH variable, you can type 'node' in and tab-complete will automatically find the exe.

   ```bsh
   PS C:\Users\me> Set-Location .\Documents\
   PS C:\Users\me\Documents> node
   # If you didn't configure your PATH variable
   PS C:\Users\me\Documents> & 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe'
   ```

   ```
   // Welcome to Node.js v12.18.0
   // Type ".help" for more information.
   > process.cwd()
   // 'C:\\Users\\me\\Documents'
   ```

AS IS

1. [OK] You should specify a path within your user file space such as `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\myproject\`.  But, option 1 is better because you don't want to forget the full path as you are working.
2. [Not Recommended] The script can be run with Administrator privileges by opening node.js with a right click "Run As Administrator".  I do not recommend this because you can cause unexpected damage to your OS and applications folder.

Comment: **Please Explain the **_1.[ok},_ **how do I specify the nodejs application using an absolute path?** @codejedi365

Comment: Editing my answer with a snippet under #1.

Comment: Does the new answer work for you? if so, you should mark accept.  If not, please comment on what further explanation you need.